# C++ cin.ignore() skip loop

Tags: c++, cin

I created a for loop in my program that makes it so you have to press enter to continue. I did this Using cin.ignore(). 
This is the basic idea of the code that I am using.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  // loop will do it for each player data
    cout << "Press Enter to Continue ";
    cin.ignore();
    system("cls");
    cout << "Playes Data" << endl;
}
```

This code works fine until the player decides to input something rather than just press enter.
From what I understand, because the player inputted something, this means that there will be a buffer. You can get rid of the buffer from just using cin.ignore. This makes it so it skips an iteration and the player doesn't have to press enter to continue. I have just included a second cin.ignore, but I don't want them to have to press enter twice. Is there some way to use the second cin.ignore only if there is a buffer, or is there some other way to deal with this?

Comment: `system()` is a *huge* grab bag of security issues. *Don't* use it - *ever*. Also; you are tying your code to Windows (with the `cls` bit), why would you do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is always a buffer.  Calling `std::cin.ignore()` by itself, with no parameter values, simply skips the next char in the buffer, which may or may not be a `'\n'` char from an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> press.

To skip everything in the buffer, up to the *next* <kbd>ENTER</kbd> press, use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
cin.ignore();
```

with

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Where the second option will ignore all characters including the newline the enter key puts into the stream.